# ¿Cuando modifico el Homestead.yaml me sale error?

Tags: laravel, vagrant

Estoy usando vagrant como maquina virtual y sobre esta instale homestead de laravel 
y cuando modifico el Homestead.yaml me sale el siguiente error

Homestead.yaml

```
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 2
provider: virtualbox

folders:
    - map: D:/sioma/Homestead/public
      to: /home/vagrant/public

sites:
    - map: siomapp.test
      to: /home/vagrant/public/usuario
      type: apache

networks:
  - type: "public_network"
    ip: "192.168.88.101"

features:
    - mariadb: false
    - ohmyzsh: false
    - webdriver: false
```

y este el error que me sale

> ```
>   C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/mingw64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/psych.rb:377:in
> ```
>
> `parse': (<unknown>): mapping values are not allowed in this context
>   at line 17 column 11 (Psy ch::SyntaxError)
>                   from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/mingw64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/psych.rb:377:in`
>   parse_stream'
>                   from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/mingw64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/psych.rb:325:in
>   `parse'
>                   from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/mingw64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/psych.rb:252:in`
>   load'
>                   from D:/sioma/Homestead/Vagrantfile:29:in `block in <top (required)>'
>                   from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.5/gems/vagrant-2.2.5/lib/vagrant/config/v2/loader.rb:37:in`
>   load'
>                   from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.5/gems/vagrant-2.2.5/lib/vagrant/config/loader.rb:126:in
>   `block (2 levels) in load'
>                   from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.5/gems/vagrant-2.2.5/lib/vagrant/config/loader.rb:119:in`
>   each'
>                   from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.5/gems/vagrant-2.2.5/lib/vagrant/config/loader.rb:119:in
>   `block in load'
>                   from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.5/gems/vagrant-2.2.5/lib/vagrant/config/loader.rb:116:in`
>   each'
>                   from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.5/gems/vagrant-2.2.5/lib/vagrant/config/loader.rb:116:in
>   `load'
>                   from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.5/gems/vagrant-2.2.5/lib/vagrant/vagrantfile.rb:29:in`
>   initialize'
>                   from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.5/gems/vagrant-2.2.5/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:792:in
>   `new'
>                   from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.5/gems/vagrant-2.2.5/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:792:in`
>   vagrantfile'
>                   from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.5/gems/vagrant-2.2.5/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:973:in
>   `process_configured_plugins'
>                   from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.5/gems/vagrant-2.2.5/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:178:in`
>   initialize'
>                   from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.5/gems/vagrant-2.2.5/bin/vagrant:145:in
>   `new'
>                   from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.5/gems/vagrant-2.2.5/bin/vagrant:145:in`
>   '

El problema radica que si modifico o quiero agregar otro dominio en el Homestead.yaml no funciona cuando guardo los cambios con el `vagrant reload --provision` o si esta apagado `vagrant up --provision`.

Sitio que quiero añadir en el Homestead.Yaml

```
- map: banapeso.test
        to: /home/vagrant/public/banapeso
        type: apache
```